# Is there a specific order in which you need to install VS extensions to enable IntelliSense, or how do you enable it?

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio-code, intellisense

A few days ago, I have installed Visual Studio Code for the first time onto my laptop. The version details are as follows:

- Version: 1.19.2;
- Commit: 490ef761b76b3f3b3832eff7a588aac891e5fe80;
- Date: 2018-01-10T15:55:03:538Z; Shell: 1.7.9;
- Rendered:    58.0.3029.110
- Node:    7.90
- Architecture:    X64

I have also installed the following extensions as required for the project (Angular 5 front-end and ASP.NET Wed API Back-end) I am working on:

- Angular Files    1.3.10  by Alexander Ivanichev
- Angular Language Service 0.1.7   by Angular
- Angular v5 Snippets  2.11.2  by John Papa
- Auto Import  1.5.3   by steoates
- Bracket Pair Colorizer   0.10.14 by CoenraadS
- C#   1.13.1  by Microsoft
- C# Extentions    1.3.0   by jchannon
- Debugger for Chrome  4.0.0   by Microsoft
- Material Icon Theme  3.2.1   by Philipp Kief
- Nuget Package Manager    1.1.6   by jmrog
- Path IntelliSense    1.4.2   by Christian Kohler
- Pretier – Code formatter 1.1.2   by Esben Petersen
- TSLint   1.0.24  by egamma
- VScode-icons 7.19.0  by Roberto Huertas

All of these extensions are enabled, but there is no IntelliSense or auto-completion, and Quick Fix (Ctrl.) Does not work. Despite numerous attempts to uninstall/re-install VS and extentions I still can't get IntelliSense or auto-completion and Quick Fix to work. Without it I am really in the dark. This sucks.

Is there a specific order in which you need to install the VS extensions to enable IntelliSense, or how do you fix this problem? I want to use Visual Studio Code, but if it's not living up to expectation I need to consider other options. I do want to give VS a go.

Comment: No, there is no install order. In which filetype is intellisense not working? Do you see any error messages in the editor or in the developer console if you run the `Developer: Toggle Developer tools` command?

Comment: Matt, thank you for clarification on the install order. Intellisense is not working for file types .cs (C#), .ts (TypeScript) and .html. In fact intellisense is not working for any file type. There are no error messages in the editor, neither in the developer console. Nothing at all. Also no red underlines where you know their should be. Any ideas?

Comment: Well as a warning to any others thinking of switching to VSCode.
After 4 months of using VSCode I can say unequivocally that this application sucks compared to IntelliJ